# Xamarin Forms Label/StackLayout Rotation Issue

Tags: android, xamarin, rotation, label, stacklayout

I'm trying to rotate some labels in xamarin forms but there are some problems. If i rotate a single label the text will trim and there will be only some letters visible, i putted every label inside a stacklayout and i rotated the stacklayout itself with -90 degree as the code below

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0"
             Rotation="-90"
             VerticalOptions="Start"
             HorizontalOptions="End">
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
        <Label Text="ABCDE" TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

the labels are rotated correctly, no text is trimmed. the problem is now that the `VerticalOptions` or `HorizontaOptions` of the stacklayout are not working properly. When i set the `VerticalOption` to "Start" it will show everything not in the top but somehow 25% from the top. The `HorizontalOptions` has another issue when i set it to "Start" or "End" like the image below:

[image]

Can anyone please help how to solve this issue, or if there is a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: noope, i'have searched over internet but it seems xamarin forms doesn't offer a simple solution in what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Lucas's answer, using margins is a valid solution.

Perhaps you should look into [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout)?  A RelativeLayout can be used to position views on screen, relative to the overall layout or to other views.

**Note:** Because of the way constraints are defined, it is possible to make more complex layouts in C# than can be specified with XAML.

Some useful links

- **RelativeLayout Docs**: 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout
- **Sample App**: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/Layout/
- **Complex Sample App**: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/BusinessTumble/

Here is a sample I tossed together using XAML.
[image: Using RelativeLayout to move labels around]

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=-30}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=25}" 
        BackgroundColor="Green" 
        Rotation="-90"
        Text="Hello World" 
        TextColor="White"
        />

    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=-10}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=25}" 
        BackgroundColor="Blue" 
        Rotation="-90"
        Text="Hello World" 
        TextColor="White"
        />

    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=10}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=25}" 
        BackgroundColor="Red" 
        Rotation="-90"
        Text="Hello World" 
        TextColor="White"
        />

    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=55}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=18}" 
        BackgroundColor="Green" 
        Rotation="-90"
        Text="123456" 
        TextColor="White"
        />

    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=75}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=120}" 
        BackgroundColor="Green" 
        Rotation="-180"
        Text="ABC DEF GHI" 
        TextColor="White"
        />

    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=120}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=200}" 
        BackgroundColor="Green" 
        Rotation="45"
        Text="JKL MNO PQR" 
        TextColor="White"
        />

    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=320}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=200}" 
        BackgroundColor="Green" 
        Rotation="-270"
        Text="Aa Bb Cc Dd" 
        TextColor="White"
        />

    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=0}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=200}" 
        BackgroundColor="Blue" 
        Rotation="-90"
        Text="Aa Bb Cc Dd" 
        TextColor="White"
        />
    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=0}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=200}" 
        BackgroundColor="Green" 
        Rotation="-70"
        Text="Aa Bb Cc Dd" 
        TextColor="White"
        />
    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=0}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=200}" 
        BackgroundColor="Blue" 
        Rotation="-50"
        Text="Aa Bb Cc Dd" 
        TextColor="White"
        />
    <Label 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=0}" 
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=200}" 
        BackgroundColor="Green" 
        Rotation="-30"
        Text="Aa Bb Cc Dd" 
        TextColor="White"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it helped me on resolving my issue. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**

When you  set the **`Rotation`** ,it  will rotate around the center of itself.So there will some 'space' on the top of the screen .

**Workaround:**

You can set the margin of the `StackLayout` .

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0"
             Rotation="-90"
             Margin="0,-130,0,0"
             VerticalOptions="Start"
             HorizontalOptions="Center">
        ...
</StackLayout>
```

And the result just like the following image.

[image]